# can't populate custom tableview header swift 3: index out of range

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

My app has a user account page that uses a tableview to return a timeline type detail. I'd like to have the actual logged-in user detail at the top in a table header.

This is handled on the useraccountViewController. I have added a function to the viewDidLoad called getUserAndTimeLine() which makes 2 api calls to my web-service to get the details for my logged in user (this view controller is opened by a segue from the login page).

I also have 2 structs one for the loggedUser, and one for the userPost that define what I am expecting to receive from the API calls. I also have arrays for the user and the posts based on the structs.

The getUserAndTimeLine() code is as follows:

```
//creates api url to get user
    let url = URL(string: "myapi.url/getuser?uid=" + user)
    //httpget sent to the api and listens for response
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
        }
        else {
            do{
                //parses the json data
                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

                //get the user data
                let thisUser = parsedData["userName"] as? String
                let thisUserImage = parsedData["userAvatar"] as? String

                let thisLoggedUser = loggedUser( userAvatar: thisUserImage, userName: thisUser)

                self.arrayOfLoggedUser.append(thisLoggedUser)

            }
            catch{
                print("parse error")
            }
        }
        }.resume()


    //creates api url to get user TL
    let tlurl = URL(string: "myapi.url?uid=" + user)
    //httpget sent to the api and listens for response
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:tlurl!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
        }
        else {
            do{
                //parses the json data
                let parsedTLData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]

                guard let posts = parsedTLData["timeline"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] else {return}
                for post in posts {
                    let thisPost = postData(postText: post["postText"] as! String, postURL: post["postURL"] as! String, postImageURL: post["postImage"] as! String,
                        postDomainName: post["postSource"] as! String,
                        postDomainLink: post["postDomainLink"] as! String,
                        postPoster: post["postPoster"] as! String,
                        postPosterAvatar: post["postPosterAvatar"] as! String,
                        postDate: post["postCreateDate"] as! String)

                    self.arrayOfPostData.append(thisPost)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()                    }
            }
            catch{
                print("parse error")
            }
        }
        }.resume()
```

In the individual cells, I am successfully able to populate my tableview (timeline) with the data from arrayOfPostData via:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("postTimeLineCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! postTimeLineCell

        cell.postImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: arrayOfPostData[indexPath.row].postImageURL))
        cell.postText.setTitle(arrayOfPost[indexPath.row].postText, for:.normal )

        cell.postDate.text = arrayOfPostData[indexPath.row].postDate

        // etc.

        return cell
}
```

However I cannot return the header:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let loggedUserHeader = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("userHeader", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! userHeader

    loggedUserHeader.userName.text = arrayOfLoggedUser[section].userName

    return loggedUserHeader
}
```

as I get an error: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) which in the output is "fatal error: Index out of range"

Can anyone help out as I'm rather stuck!

Comment: presumably, `arrayOfGrabbUser` doesn't have an entry for `[section]` - but you haven't included any reference to how the array is defined...

Comment: sorry - it should be arrayOfLoggedUser. How do I check if there is a section for it? I've certainly set in the numberofsections for the tableview a value of 1, and the number of rows in section to the arrayPostData.count

Comment: You need to check exactly what's in `arrayOfLoggedUser` when you get to `viewForHeaderInSection ` - set a breakpoint and have a look

Comment: Ok thanks. I have certainly verified the expected data is present after the api call and after appending it to   `arrayOfLoggedUser` via `self.arrayOfLoggedUser.append(thisLoggedUser)` but not at the 'viewForHeaderInSection'

Comment: so the arrayOfGrabbUser is empty when it reaches `viewForHeaderInSection` but I'm not sure why - it definitely has the expected data after the api call.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous data is almost always the problem.

The user array will be populated after the API call has completed - but you will be refreshing the tableView before that.

Simplest thing is to put a check in `viewForHeaderInSection` and if the array.count < section index then just return with nothing, or a default value

Comment: I understand what you're saying (that the data doesn't exist when it loads the header), but i don't understand why the same approach for the cells (make the api call, send to the view) does work or how i can get the header to work in the same way. returning nothing or a default value wouldn't work: it needs to show the logged in user's details.

Comment: So i ended up making the user api call on the login page before the segue to the user account and storing them in global variables, so when i come to the user page i was able to get the detail from the header for that. so although i still don't understand why it worked for the table cells and not the header, i got round the issue.